# undefined method `caches_action' for ApplicationController:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I'm trying to upgrade to rails 4 beta 1, but I've a bit of a problem.

This is, in short, how my application controller looks like.

```
class ApplicationController < ApplicationController
  caches_action :method
end
```

`caches_action` is moved out to it's own gem in Rails 4, so including the gem should fix the problem.

```
gem "actionpack-action_caching", github: "rails/actionpack-action_caching"
```

But when I run my requests specs or visit the application in a browser I get this error.

```
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:3:in `<class:ApplicationController>': undefined method `caches_action' for ApplicationController:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Why is that?

- Rails 4.0.0.beta1
- Ruby 2.0.0
- Rspec 2.13.1

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you `require 'actionpack-action_caching'` before using `caches_action`?

Comment: I just tried `gem 'actionpack-action_caching', github: 'rails/actionpack-action_caching', require: "actionpack-action_caching"`, which resulted in `cannot load such file -- actionpack-action_caching (LoadError)`

Comment: Oooups, sorry. I took a look at the code, you need to `require actionpack/action_caching` rather than `require 'actionpack-action_caching'` (slash instead of minus.) As the caching is not a part of core anymore, you need to explicitly `require` it in top of every file you use it in.

Comment: Adding `require "actionpack/action_caching"` to `application.rb` worked. Write it as an answer below and I'll accepted it. Thanks.

Comment: I am having this problem and the suggested solution does not solve it.  Anyone?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As the caching is not a part of core anymore, you need to explicitly require it in top of every file you use it in:

```
require 'actionpack/action_caching'
```

Comment: This issue response suggests that you shouldn't have to require it explicitly: https://github.com/rails/actionpack-action_caching/pull/11

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in Rails 4, they have extracted cache part into separate gems

if you are getting error for action caching then you need to add below gem

```
gem 'actionpack-action_caching'
```

for page caching have to add

```
gem 'actionpack-page_caching'
```

I also played around then I figure out that, have not added gem to do the same.

hope that will works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Iam using rails as an API `rails new AppName --api`
I got it working by adding

```
include ActionController::Caching
```

in `class ApplicationController < ActionController::API`